# Best practices for deep linking between Android, iOS and Web apps

Tags: mobile-web

What are the best practices when it comes to managing Deep Linking? We have iOS, Android and Web (responsive) versions of our app built, but I am not sure how to best handle the deep linking when the user has the app installed on the device or not.

Should we direct the user automatically into the app?  Should we ask first?  If they don't have the app installed should we send them to the App Store?  Any good research done on this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concerns with "Deep Linking". Are you wondering how to handle  `http://www.cats.com/hats` vs `/hats`?

Answer (score 1):

**Handling "App Recommendation"**

You don't want to annoy your users, but you do want them to be aware of an alternative browsing solution that enhances their browsing experience. To accomplish this, we need to do the following:

- Only notify them of the app if they're viewing the website from a mobile app
- Notify them in an unobtrusive way that is easily dismissed
- *REMEMBER* if they have dismissed in the past (and don't re-ask)
- If they choose to download the app, make the download experience short + sweet
- Potentially provide a "more  info" link that talks about the benefits of the app vs the responsive website

Even if you didn't have a responsive website, most users would still prefer to be able to browse your website without being *forced* to download an app. Not all users are reoccurring users, and a forced app download on their first visit may deter them from returning.